# Task.Run Serial Communications

Tags: c#, mvvm, serial-port, task-parallel-library, async-await

I really have enjoyed using MVVM and async/await, so naturally, I hacked together a project to make a new development (MVVM) which communicates with devices over serial to work and the UI be responsive.  My driver classes are synchronous calls, which communicate with the device over serial and can take time (although, typically not) depending on how much data is returned, if I get the appropriate return or if the driver should continue to wait a few more seconds to see if the appropriate return comes up, etc.

Anyways, what I ended up doing was wrapping the communications in an await Task.Run(()=>{}); wrapper.  This way, from my UI perspective, when the user clicks the button, magically it gets thrown on the Thread Pool and my UI stays responsive while processing the task.

Is the below implementation incorrect?  Since I'm communicating over Serial, isn't my work technically I/O bound work instead of CPU bound work (Task.Run is supposedly to be used only for CPU bound work, from what I've read)?  The below method is called in my View Model by doing:

```
var returnVal = await _objName.InitAsync();
```

Then the Task.Run call....

```
    public async Task<bool> InitAsync()
    {
        bool returnVal = false;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(COMMAND_DELAY_MILLISECONDS);
            returnVal = _obj.InitiateProvision();
        });

        return returnVal;
    }
```

The bool return value simply states if the command was successful or not.  The code works just fine as I've been testing it for about a month now with no problems, but I'm not sure if it is best...  Is there a "better" way to do this while still being able to maintain asynchronous operations?  Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: What is the point of sleeping before you call `InitiateProvision`? Also is `InitiateProvision` slow?

Comment: Just to add a brief delay before sending the command, I have about 3 commands I call sequentially like this so I added this to give some time between the calls.  I'm not sure if this is best either... working with Serial ports is fairly new to me.

Comment: You could have returned the return value of _obj.InitiateProvision from Task.Run thus avoiding capturing the returnVal local variable avoiding the creation of types and instantiations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Task.Run` just so you can have a delay before you do your command just use a [delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and don't tie up the threadpool.

```
public async Task<bool> InitAsync()
{
    bool returnVal = false;

    await Task.Delay(COMMAND_DELAY_MILLISECONDS).ConfigureAwait(false);
    returnVal = _obj.InitiateProvision();

    return returnVal;
}
```

You said you had 3 commands, you can just do all three commands in a row if it fits your design, you can have more than one `await` in a function.

```
public async Task<bool> InitAsync()
{
    bool returnVal = false;

    await Task.Delay(COMMAND_DELAY_MILLISECONDS).ConfigureAwait(false);
    returnVal = _obj.InitiateProvision();

    if(returnVal == true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(COMMAND_DELAY_MILLISECONDS).ConfigureAwait(false);
        returnVal = _obj.CommandTwo();
    }

    if(returnVal == true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(COMMAND_DELAY_MILLISECONDS).ConfigureAwait(false);
        returnVal = _obj.CommandThree();
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

The `.ConfigureAwait(false)` makes it so the function does not need to return to the UI thread when it continues its work after the `await` and can make the program faster due to it not needing to wait its turn in the UI thread.

Comment: I just saw your updated comment - the InitiateProvision call is slow and is what ties up the UI.  The delay is just used to allow some cushion between calls - I will definitely add the Task.Delay, but is it still OK to wrap the InitiateProvision call in a Task.Run.

Comment: OK, fantastic!  So "await Task.Delay" for the delays, and wrap the slow call of InitiateProvision and similar in "await Task.Run"?

Comment: I would still try to avoid using `Task.Run` in your function. Instead you can still use `async` and do `await Task.Delay` but instead of having `Task.Run` in this function do `await Task.Run(() => InitAsync());` so you have have the ***caller*** wrap the function in a Task.Run.

Comment: The reason you do that is if you ever called `InitAsync` from a non UI thread you don't need the `Task.Run` so this gives you the flexibility of choosing to tie up a threadpool thread or not depending on your needs.